# Protection against SQL injection in PHP in a search mask

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

Hello I want to use parameter binding.
The search query is only internal. This means that only a few users will be queried. The query should only be made in numbers and this character "/". Can you help me?

```
**$query =
  "SELECT * 
   FROM 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz], 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz], 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] ";
$query .= 
   " WHERE 
        [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz].auftrag_nr=[hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz].aunr_n";
$query.=
   " AND [hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz].auftrag_nr_v=[hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand].auftrag_nr";
$query.= " AND kd_auftrag LIKE '%$_POST[suchbegriff]%'";
      
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    
echo "<h2>";
echo $row['kd_auftrag'];
echo "</h2>";
echo "<h2>";
echo $row['auftrag_nr'];
echo "</h2>";
    echo "<h2>";
echo $row['plan_auftrag'];
echo "</h2>";  
    echo "</h1>";
echo $row['masch_nr'];
echo "</h2>";
echo "</h2>";
echo $row['erranf_dat'];
echo "</h2>";
    echo "</h2>";**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sqlsrv\_prepare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177094/how-to-use-sqlsrv-prepare-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters in sqlsrv_query in an array form. So you could do something like this:

```
**$query =
  "SELECT * 
   FROM 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz], 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz], 
      [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] ";
$query .= 
   " WHERE 
        [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz].auftrag_nr=[hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz].aunr_n";
$query.=
   " AND [hydadm].[v_ade_auftragsnetz].auftrag_nr_v=[hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand].auftrag_nr";
$query.= " AND kd_auftrag LIKE '%?%'";

$parameters = [$_POST[suchbegriff]];

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query,$parameters);
```

The sqlsrv_query takes the parameters in the order defined in the array.